# Actualizar Android Studio 2.3 y tener error Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?

Tags: android-studio

Acabo de actualizar el `Android studio de 2.3` y me marca como error `Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?` pero compilar y hacer correr la app, sin ningún problema, es decir parece que se desconfigurado algo y me marca error en muchas lineas.

He probado lo típico `clean/build` limpiar el proyecto y volver hacer build, pero sigue mostrándome algunas lineas con errores.

Comment: Hola amigo @Webserveis, saludos. Como comentario, he encontrado problemas al actualizar  las versiones de SDK tools y librerías de soporte a 25.0.1+, en este caso son necesarios workarounds y también al actualizar Android Studio. =(

Comment: Evitemos usar [tag:error]. Más detalle en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/65

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muchos detalles que han surgido al actualizar tanto librerías de soporte como Android Studio, en este caso **invalida el caché**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución puede ser en "`Gradle Scripts/build.gradle(Module:app)`". En la última línea (remarcado en negrita) solo necesitas borrar un número y reescribirlo a como lo tenías antes de borrar.

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso core:3.0.1'
```

- Después de esto, Android Studio te mostrará una opción llamada "Synchronise".
- Seleccionala y espera a que recargue.

Answer (score 1):

borra el directorio `.idea` de la aplicación, luego en el menú de archivo dale a invalidar cache y reinicia:

[image: Menú de invalidar cache]

Muy importante que borres el directorio `.idea` antes de hacer esto.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica si `compileSdkVersion` y la targetSdkVersion  tienen el mismo valor

Lo otro que puede funcionar es añadiendo `buildtoolsversion 26.0.2`