# Problemas tras actualizar Android Studio a la última versión

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Desde que actualice *Android Studio* a 2.3 estoy teniendo problemas que no influyen a la hora de utilizar la aplicación en el móvil, pero si me marca errores desde *Android Studio* y no sé si en un futuro tendré problemas, por eso quiero solucionarlos.

El primero es en el `gradle` y es el siguiente:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.1.0, 25.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0 and com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Este es mi `gradle`, en `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'` es donde recibo el mensaje de arriba.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "otrointento.dos"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/circleimageview/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Y el otro problema es en este `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/base_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPersonas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="#f4f4f4"
        android:dividerHeight="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#46b1bb"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#3d979f"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#46b1bb"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#3d979f"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#45baba"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/icon_btn_flo_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_btn_flo_1"
            fab:fab_label="@string/btn_flo_1"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

> Failed to instantiate one or more classes
>
> The following classes could not be instantiated:

Comment: prueba con alt+intro a la lineas que te salen en amarillo, para actualizar a la nueva versión dejando el buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

Comment: Acabas de descubrir un bug, un error de Android. Ha sido reportado aquí: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236471 vuelve a una versión anterior, como se ha indicado en las respuestas, mientras lo corrigen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> All com.android.support **libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification** (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.1.0, 25.0.2. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Puedes conservar

```
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

y cambiar las versiones de las librerías de diseño y compatibilidad a la misma versión, si es que existe, al parecer no estan listadas todas las versiones en la documentación oficial :
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

pero al día de hoy la última versión es la 25.2.0 :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegura tener instalada la versión indicada en tu `Build.gradle` y esta versión deben tener tus library. **Asegura que la `buildToolsVersion` definida sea una existente**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuando al mensaje de la dependencia `com.android.support:renderscript` :

> com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2 is incompatible with support
>   library 25.2.0 revision

Es un detalle reportado a Google : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236471

por lo que se puede optar en usar :

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

---

Al actualizar de una versión Android Studio a una más nueva es aconsejable invalidar caché :

[Actualizar Android Studio 2.3 y tener error Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52933/actualizar-android-studio-2-3-y-tener-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactiv)

Comment: He *invalidado el caché* y he puesto la versión *25.0.2* pero al sincronizar me dice **Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.0.2** y lo mismo en `appcompat-v7` y al hacer clic en "Install Repository and sync project" no hace nada..

Comment: @UserNameYo usa la versión 25.0.1 o la 25.2.0 que es la última hasta el día de hoy.

Comment: Gracias! Ahora si, solucionado!

Answer (score 0):

Ajusta la versión de la librería a la misma que está en `buildToolsVersion` o viceversa.

Puedes dejar la librería de soporte así:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.2'
```

o dejar la `buildToolsVersion` así

```
buildToolsVersion "25.1.0"
```

La idea es que usen la misma versión.

Comment: Ya había probado así `buildToolsVersion "25.1.0"` pero recibo este error `Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.1.0`, le doy a install, pero no instala "All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;25.1.0"

Comment: Prueba actualizandolo desde el sdk manager, dentro de este ->  Tools>Android SDK Build-Tools[Versión]

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero la última que me sale es 25.0.2, no puedo instalar la 25.1.0 ya que no me sale, alguna idea?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "25.1.0" no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Referente a esto:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.1.0, 25.0.2. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Me ha pasado lo mismo con otro ejemplo

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.2.0, 25.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0

y he tenido que añadir la línea de `compile''` específica, es decir, me mostraba error con esto:

```
//    android support
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Después he añadido la librería específica que me indicaba (`com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0`):

```
//    android support
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Supongo que antes estaba dentro de otra librería y ahora la han separado.

---

Referente al error del xml, puede estar relacionado al error del gradle por las librerías y se solucione igual, aunque diría que el error es que la librería que usas tiene alguna incompatibilidad con otras librerías actualizadas.

Estos objetos supongo:

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: He probado añadiendo `com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0` pero nada.. Sigue igual, por otro lado suponía que el error era con esa librería pero la tengo actualizada, no sé que más podría hacer. Gracias @MarcGV

Comment: Customtabs es la que me daba error a mi, a ti te da otra y debes añadir la tuya. Debes añadir la de renderscript con la versión 25.1.0 porque usas esa version con las otras librerias de android:support. Asi que añade esto: compile 'com.android.support:renderscript:25.1.0'

Comment: "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:renderscript:25.1.0" y cuando hago click en "Install Repository and sync project" no hace nada

Comment: Tienes el buildToolsVersion en 25.1.0 tambien? Todo a 25.1.0, sino deberas ponerlo todo a 25.0.2

Comment: He probado todo en 25.1.0 o 25.0.2 pero me pasa lo que te acabo de decir en el comentario anterior