# Actualize de Android Studio 2.2 a 2.3 y ahora mi apps no funcionan

Tags: android-studio

Actualizé mi entorno de desarrollo Android Studio de la version 2.2.x a la 2.3.1 y ahora ninguna de las aplicacines se ejecutan ni en el dispositivo virtual ni en uno real.

Comment: si se ejecutan te deben devolver algún error en el logcat, otra cosa es asegurate de subir las dependencias app.gradle en amarillo deberán estar resaltadas.

Comment: No creo que no se ejecuten, lo que sucede es que no se pueden crear es asì? Revisa si alguna de estas preguntas es similar:  
    http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52933/actualizar-android-studio-2-3-y-tener-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactiv
    http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53666/problemas-tras-actualizar-android-studio-a-la-%C3%BAltima-versi%C3%B3n

Comment: Revise los enlaces que me recomendastes pero el problema que se me presenta es distinto, cuando ejecuto en un dispositivo virtual dura  tres o cuatro veces el tiempo que tardaba antes de actualizar a 2.3.1 y me aparece este mensaje: "Waiting for target device to come on line";al final veo este mensaje en una ventana: "Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online". En el dispositivo real simplemente no se ejecuta. Al ejecutarla en un dispositivo real no se abre sino que se muestra el mensaje: "Lamentablemente la aplicacion app se detuvo"

Comment: Olvide comentar antes que tambien habia actualizado (supuestamente) de Gradle 2.3.1  a la version 3.3 en los proyectos que me dan este error.