# Problemas al usar renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando una librería para usar el efecto **Blur** en mi `DialogFragment` y todo funciona perfecto, pero en el `gradle` me sale un aviso

> all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to rutime crashes). Found version 25.3.1, 25.0.2. Examples incliude com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Este aviso solamente me sale si activo `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled` poniéndolo **true** si lo pongo **false** no recibo el aviso. Pero lo necesito para usar la librería que comento arriba.

`gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "prueba.dos"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'
    compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

La librería en concreto es [BlurDialogFragment](https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment).

Sé qué cree hace un tiempo una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53666/problemas-tras-actualizar-android-studio-a-la-%C3%BAltima-versi%C3%B3n) con un problema similar, pero no consigo solucionarlo y no sé si dejarlo así. ¿Tendré problemas en un futuro?

Gracias!

**EDITO1:**

He estado investigando un poco y la única clase que utiliza `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true` es `RenderScriptBlurHelper` (De la librería que he comentado)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Simple helper used to blur a bitmap thanks to render script.
 */
final class RenderScriptBlurHelper {

    /**
     * Log cat
     */
    private static final String TAG = RenderScriptBlurHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Non instantiable class.
     */
    private RenderScriptBlurHelper() {

    }

    /**
     * blur a given bitmap
     *
     * @param sentBitmap       bitmap to blur
     * @param radius           blur radius
     * @param canReuseInBitmap true if bitmap must be reused without blur
     * @param context          used by RenderScript, can be null if RenderScript disabled
     * @return blurred bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap doBlur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius, boolean canReuseInBitmap, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (canReuseInBitmap) {
            bitmap = sentBitmap;
        } else {
            bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
        }

        if (bitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) {
            // RenderScript hates RGB_565 so we convert it to ARGB_8888
            // (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563299/
            // defect-of-image-with-scriptintrinsicblur-from-support-library)
            bitmap = convertRGB565toARGB888(bitmap);
        }

        try {
            final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
            final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                    Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
            final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
            final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
            script.setRadius(radius);
            script.setInput(input);
            script.forEach(output);
            output.copyTo(bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (RSRuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "RenderScript known error : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71347 "
                    + "continue with the FastBlur approach.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Bitmap convertRGB565toARGB888(Bitmap bitmap) {
        return bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }
}
```

Y he probado eliminando esto:

```
 try {
            final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
            final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                    Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
            final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
            final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
            script.setRadius(radius);
            script.setInput(input);
            script.forEach(output);
            output.copyTo(bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (RSRuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "RenderScript known error : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71347 "
                    + "continue with the FastBlur approach.");
        }
```

Y ya no lo necesito activar, además funciona perfectamente el efecto **Blur**, pero no sé hasta que punto influye la parte del código que he eliminado. Alguna idea?

Comment: Sí, lo he comentado en la pregunta, pero la acabo de editar con más información del problema y como lo he solucionado, pero no sé hasta que punto puede influir mi solución, alguna idea? Gracias! @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si defines  `compileSdkVersion 25` debes tener versiones similares en las librerías, si son diferentes te sugiere cambiarlas para evitar problemas.

> all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to rutime crashes). Found
>   version 25.3.1, 25.0.2. Examples incliude
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and
>   com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Para saber cual es la última versión y configurar, coloca el puntero del mouse sobre la dependencia y te indicará cual es la última versión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si estas usando:

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

usas las clases:

```
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
```

Pero puedes no usar el modo activado, usa las clases normales:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
```

Comment: Como puedes ver en mi `gradle` están correctamente, al menos yo no veo ninguna mal

Comment: elimina renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true y usa las clases normales.

Comment: Haciendo lo que comentas funciona perfectamente! Qué diferencia hay entre usar unas o las otras? Gracias! @Jorgesys

Comment: simplemente defines usar o no el soporte para RenderScript!

Answer (score 1):

No deberías tener problema ninguno. Me explico, eso pese a que te sale en rojo señalado, no es un problema, es mas, te deja compilar y ejecutar. Lo que te está diciendo es que hay alguna libreria por ahí con una versión de algo menor a la que tu tienes en tus archivos de gradle y que deberían de tener todas la misma.

Posiblemente la librería que usas para el efecto blur está tirando de support o alguna otra de google y tiene un versión menor a las que tu tienes en tu archivo Gradle.

Como ya te he dicho, no te preocupes por ello, es cierto que es un engorro ver esa linea roja ahi pero si te fijas te debería dejar ejecutar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! He editado la pregunta, dime que opinas, por favor :) @Curro

Comment: Yo creo que no debería afectarte en nada por lo que comentas tu pero mejor pruebalo, es decir, ejecuta la app, haz lo que tengas que hacer con ella y mira si no te da problemas ni nada. Sinceramente ahora eres tu quien debe ver si te da errores o no, nosotros desde aqui es mas complicado jajaja ;)

Comment: Probé y todo funciona correctamente y sin errores, pero me pareció raro, ya que no creo que añadan código para hacer 'bulto' o igual si jajaj