# Android DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicación,  tengo el error DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR al ejecutar el proyecto en otra computadora para seguir avanzando.

Estos mensajes son lo que se muestran:
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs

Session 'app': Error Installing APKs.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las computadoras tiene la misma versión de android studio.

Comment: desactiva instan run, vacia la cache del proyecto con clean y después dale build, para posteriormente activar el instant run

Comment: Realice tus pasos, no muestra el mensaje, se instala la nueva versión pero no ejecuta la aplicación.

Comment: Te muestra algún error ahora? También puedes probar de crear un proyecto nuevo para ver si Android studio compila y instala bien, para ir descartando posibles errores.
Mírate también eso si has actualizado android studio y es cuando te empieza a dar problemas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52933/actualizar-android-studio-2-3-y-tener-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactiv

Comment: Ya realice ese paso, tampoco se soluciona.

Comment: prueba en definir exported a true en androidmanifest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525954/android-studio-client-not-ready-yet los huaweis son un poco perculiares en el tema de install/debug

Answer (score 1):

Como opción puedes deshabilitar el Instant run :

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run` > des selecciona : `Enable Instant Run`

**Pero recuerda que si tienes este error puedes dar ok y simplemente sobreescribira la aplicación, lo cual no causa ningun problema**

[image]

> Las computadoras tiene la misma versión de android studio.

Simplemente la aplicación que esta instalada fue firmada con otro Keystore de debug y al tratar de instalar otra firmada con un keystore diferente por esa razón muestra el mensaje

Puedes eliminar la aplicación actual y se instalara sin problema.

Comment: He realizado los pasos, pero ahora al instalar la aplicación se cierra enseguida, con el siguiente mensaje. Application terminated. También probé desinstalar y volver a ejecutar el proyecto, pero me daba el mismo error.

Comment: "instalar la aplicación se cierra enseguida", "Application terminated" Si inicia y se cierra, ahora es error de tu aplicación, debes revisar el LogCat pero es independiente a esto que preguntas.

Comment: Haber, ejecuto el instalador de desde donde se inicio por primera vez el proyecto y funciona normal, vuelvo a ejecutar desde la otra (donde copie el proyecto) y se cierra. Eso sucede

Comment: Este me muestra  "$ adb shell am start -n "com.---.ventas.---/com.---.ventas.---.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 12369 on device huawei-mha_l09-UGM0217115000416
Application terminated."

Comment: **Eso es un problema en el dispositivo donde se va a instalar el .apk, no tiene que ver con el problema de la pregunta.** Me parece que se desconecto ".Waiting for process to come online Connected to process 12369 on device huawei-mha_l09-UGM0217115000416 Application terminated.""