# Android Studio error al crear una clase java

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studio no me permite crear clases java dentro de mi carpeta del proyecto.

Lo último que realice fue que actualice el `jdk` de la versión `1.7` a la versión `1.8` ya que una de las librerías que tengo en mi gradle me lo solicitaba.

Este es el mensaje error que me muestra cuando intento crear una clase, ya intente varios métodos como borrar el directorio `.AndroidStudio` y volver a configurar de nuevo pero sigue igual.

[image: Error al crear clase java]

Este es mi archivo gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.discomsc.eqbe"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Si reinicie mi Android Studio para ver si así se corregía pero sigue igual

Comment: Ya agregue mi archivo build.gradle a mi pregunta

Comment: [La misma situación fue planteada ayer en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45534524/5587982). La solución fue: hacer copia de seguridad de la carpeta `.AndroidStudio`, borrarla e instalar todo desde cero.

Comment: Hola @user4028047 , primero que prueba invalidando cache : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52933/actualizar-android-studio-2-3-y-tener-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactiv cuando surgen problemas al actualizar algún componente, regularmente esta es la solución.

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus comentarios disculpen la demora en dar respuesta, voy a intentar con esas opciones, gracias.